# Using HasManyThrough in Laravel

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent

I have the following structure:

**orders**
id
name

**products**
id
name

**items**
id
order_id
product_id
quantity

The relationships are as follows:

Order

```
public function items(){
 return $this->hasMany(Item::class)
}

public function products(){
 return $this->hasManyThrough(Product::class, Item::class);
}
```

Item

```
public function order(){
 return $this->belongsTo(Order::class);
}

public function product(){
 return $this->belongsTo(Product::class);
}
```

Product

```
public function items(){
 return $this->hasMany(Item::class);
}
```

I wish to get all products for the order doing something like this:
$order->items()->products()->get() using the hasManyThrough method, but I must be doing it wrong since it tries to look for item_id in the products table.

Answer (score 0):

I realized that I do not need many through, I just need to use items table as a pivot table, defining the relationship on the Order model just like this:

```
public function products(){
 return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class, 'items');
}
```